# Change the legend shape from rectangele to circle using google visualization Chart

Tags: google-visualization

How I can change the shape of legend for Google visualization chart without changing the graphs of diagrams ?

Comment: The shape of the markers in the legend is not configurable.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for this.

Comment: I have just submitted a feature request https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1943&thanks=1943&ts=1427969500